# How do you clear the SQL Server transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I'm not a SQL expert, and I'm reminded of the fact every time I need to do something beyond the basics. I have a test database that is not large in size, but the transaction log definitely is. How do I clear out the transaction log?

Comment: [How to use the DBCC SHRINKFILE statement to shrink the transaction log file in SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907511)

Comment: There should be a command in Managment Studio: "Click to Shrink Log" and you're done.

Answer (score 879, accepted):

Making a log file smaller should really be reserved for scenarios where it encountered unexpected growth which you do not expect to happen again. If the log file will grow to the same size again, not very much is accomplished by shrinking it temporarily. Now, depending on the recovery goals of your database, these are the actions you should take.

### First, take a full backup

Never make any changes to your database without ensuring you can restore it should something go wrong.

### If you care about point-in-time recovery

(And by point-in-time recovery, I mean you care about being able to restore to anything other than a full or differential backup.)

Presumably your database is in `FULL` recovery mode. If not, then make sure it is:

```
ALTER DATABASE testdb SET RECOVERY FULL;

-- and take another full backup here
-- so log backups are possible
```

Even if you are taking regular full backups, the log file will grow and grow until you perform a *log* backup - this is for your protection, not to needlessly eat away at your disk space. You should be performing these log backups quite frequently, according to your recovery objectives. For example, if you have a business rule that states you can afford to lose no more than 15 minutes of data in the event of a disaster, you should have a job that backs up the log every 15 minutes. Here is a script that will generate timestamped file names based on the current time (but you can also do this with maintenance plans etc., just don't choose any of the shrink options in maintenance plans, they're awful).

```
DECLARE @path nvarchar(4000) = CONCAT(
  N'\\backup_share\log\testdb_',  
  CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112), N'_',
  REPLACE(CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 108),':',''),
  N'.trn');

BACKUP LOG foo TO DISK = @path WITH INIT, COMPRESSION;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
GO 2 -- run twice to ensure file wrap-around
```

Note that `\\backup_share\` should be on a different machine that represents a different underlying storage device. Backing these up to the same machine (or to a different machine that uses the same underlying disks, or a different VM that's on the same physical host) does not really help you, since if the machine blows up, you've lost your database *and* its backups. Depending on your network infrastructure it may make more sense to backup locally and then transfer them to a different location behind the scenes; in either case, you want to get them off the primary database machine as quickly as possible.

Now, once you have regular log backups running, it should be reasonable to shrink the log file to something more reasonable than whatever it's blown up to now. This does *not* mean running `SHRINKFILE` over and over again until the log file is 1 MB - even if you are backing up the log frequently, it still needs to accommodate the sum of any concurrent transactions that can occur. Log file autogrow events are expensive, since SQL Server has to zero out the files (unlike data files when instant file initialization is enabled), and user transactions have to wait while this happens. You want to do this grow-shrink-grow-shrink routine as little as possible, and you certainly don't want to make your users pay for it.

Note that you may need to back up the log twice before a shrink is possible (thanks Robert).

So, you need to come up with a practical size for your log file. Nobody here can tell you what that is without knowing a lot more about your system, but if you've been frequently shrinking the log file and it has been growing again, a good watermark is probably 10-50% higher than the largest it's been. Let's say that comes to 200 MB, and you want any subsequent autogrowth events to be 50 MB, then you can adjust the log file size this way (where `'yourdb_log'` is the *logical* name of your database's log file, which you can find in [`sys.database_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql)):

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test1 
  MODIFY FILE
  (NAME = N'yourdb_log', SIZE = 200MB, FILEGROWTH = 50MB);
GO
```

Note that if the log file is currently > 200 MB, you may need to run this first:

```
USE yourdb;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(N'yourdb_log', 200); -- unit is MB
GO
```

### If you don't care about point-in-time recovery

If this is a test database, and you don't care about point-in-time recovery, then you should make sure that your database is in `SIMPLE` recovery mode.

```
ALTER DATABASE testdb SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

Putting the database in `SIMPLE` recovery mode will make sure that SQL Server re-uses portions of the log file (essentially phasing out inactive transactions) instead of growing to keep a record of *all* transactions (like `FULL` recovery does until you back up the log). `CHECKPOINT` events will help control the log and make sure that it doesn't need to grow unless you generate a lot of t-log activity between `CHECKPOINT`s.

Next, you should make absolute sure that this log growth was truly due to an abnormal event (say, an annual spring cleaning or rebuilding your biggest indexes), and not due to normal, everyday usage. If you shrink the log file to a ridiculously small size, and SQL Server just has to grow it again to accommodate your normal activity, what did you gain? Were you able to make use of that disk space you freed up only temporarily? If you need an immediate fix, then you can run the following:

```
USE yourdb;
GO
CHECKPOINT;
CHECKPOINT; -- run twice to ensure file wrap-around
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(N'yourdb_log', 200); -- unit is MB
GO
```

Otherwise, set an appropriate size and growth rate. As per the example in the point-in-time recovery case, you can use the same code and logic to determine what file size is appropriate and set reasonable autogrowth parameters.

### Some things you don't want to do

- **Back up the log with `TRUNCATE_ONLY` option and then `SHRINKFILE`**. For one, this `TRUNCATE_ONLY` option has been deprecated and is no longer available in current versions of SQL Server. Second, if you are in `FULL` recovery model, this will destroy your log chain and require a new, full backup.
- **Detach the database, delete the log file, and re-attach**. I can't emphasize how dangerous this can be. Your database may not come back up, it may come up as suspect, you may have to revert to a backup (if you have one), etc. etc.
- **Use the "shrink database" option**. `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` and the maintenance plan option to do the same are bad ideas, especially if you really only need to resolve a log problem issue. Target the file you want to adjust and adjust it independently, using `DBCC SHRINKFILE` or `ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE` (examples above).
- **Shrink the log file to 1 MB**. This looks tempting because, hey, SQL Server will let me do it in certain scenarios, and look at all the space it frees! Unless your database is read only (and it is, you should mark it as such using `ALTER DATABASE`), this will absolutely just lead to many unnecessary growth events, as the log has to accommodate current transactions regardless of the recovery model. What is the point of freeing up that space temporarily, just so SQL Server can take it back slowly and painfully?
- **Create a second log file**. This will provide temporarily relief for the drive that has filled your disk, but this is like trying to fix a punctured lung with a band-aid. You should deal with the problematic log file directly instead of just adding another potential problem. Other than redirecting some transaction log activity to a different drive, a second log file really does nothing for you (unlike a second data file), since only one of the files can ever be used at a time. [Paul Randal also explains why multiple log files can bite you later](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/).

### Be proactive

Instead of shrinking your log file to some small amount and letting it constantly autogrow at a small rate on its own, set it to some reasonably large size (one that will accommodate the sum of your largest set of concurrent transactions) and set a reasonable autogrow setting as a fallback, so that it doesn't have to grow multiple times to satisfy single transactions and so that it will be relatively rare for it to ever have to grow during normal business operations.

The worst possible settings here are 1 MB growth or 10% growth. Funny enough, these are the defaults for SQL Server (which I've complained about and [asked for changes to no avail](https://web.archive.org/web/20140108204835/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/415343)) - 1 MB for data files, and 10% for log files. The former is much too small in this day and age, and the latter leads to longer and longer events every time (say, your log file is 500 MB, first growth is 50 MB, next growth is 55 MB, next growth is 60.5 MB, etc. etc. - and on slow I/O, believe me, you will really notice this curve).

### Further reading

Please don't stop here; while much of the advice you see out there about shrinking log files is inherently bad and even potentially disastrous, there are some people who care more about data integrity than freeing up disk space.

- [A blog post I wrote in 2009, when I saw a few "here's how to shrink the log file" posts spring up](https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/27/oh-the-horror-please-stop-telling-people-they-should-shrink-their-log-files).
- [A blog post Brent Ozar wrote four years ago, pointing to multiple resources, in response to a SQL Server Magazine article that should *not* have been published](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/).
- [A blog post by Paul Randal explaining why t-log maintenance is important](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/importance-of-proper-transaction-log-size-management/) and [why you shouldn't shrink your data files, either](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/).
- [Mike Walsh has a great answer covering some of these aspects too, including reasons why you might not be able to shrink your log file immediately](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space).

Comment: Point-in-time recovery isn't the only reason to use full recovery model. The main reason is to prevent data loss. Your potential for data loss is the length between backups. If you're only doing a daily backup, your potential for data loss is 24 hours. If you then add log backups every half hour, your potential for data loss becomes 30 minutes. Additionally, log backups are required to perform any sort of piecemeal restore (like to recover from corruption).

Comment: That aside, this is the most complete and correct answer given on this page.

Comment: @Robert thanks, I added clarification to what I mean by the two different categories.

Comment: I would also want to add that clearing the log is done by backing up the log (in full or bulk-logged recovery) or a checkpoint (in simple recovery). However, if you are in a situation where you must shrink the log file, that's not enough. You need to cause the currently active VLF to cycle back to the start of the log file. You can force this in SQL 2008 and newer by issuing two log backups or checkpoints back-to-back. The first one clears it and the second one cycles it back to the start of the file.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for this; I had thought that shrinking the database was a bad idea, and sure enough, you (and Brent) confirmed it.

Comment: I used to think that recovery model=simple meant no logging.  Now that I understand that THERE IS SOME LOGGING, even while the recovery model is set to simple... I wonder why Mgmt Studio does not offer Backup type=Log, for recovery model=simple.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison because at any point, log records could be purged. What would be the point of allowing you to backup a log which is incomplete? In simple recovery, the log is only really used to allow for rollbacks of transactions. Once a transaction has been committed or rolled back, the next second it could be gone from the log.

Comment: @RobertLDavis this is one the top most complete and correct answers on the site.

Comment: @AaronBertrand We recently lost our connection to an off-site log shipping disk, so the logs grew rapidly until we were able to restore the connection and catch up.  Is this considered a valid  *"unexpected growth"* scenario as you have described?

Comment: @SirCrispalot Of course, unless you expect to lose the off-site disk regularly, in which case you should either log ship elsewhere first and then pass it on (so that production doesn't depend on the reliability of the off-site disk), or stop using an unreliable off-site disk. :-)

Comment: Under the category "If you don't care about point in time recovery..." - DEVELOPMENT - NOT LIVE - database - we had a rogue transaction holding onto the transaction log. An hour after cancellation, it was still logging AND was sitting at twice the allowed logfile limit for the repository (obviously an incorrect incorrect setup parameter to be addressed). We used DBCC OPENTRAN to identify the spid of the trans. holding onto the log and kill it. The log shrank after that. Was a last resort for us and as said before likely only viable in DEV/TEST env where point-in-time recovery not required.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I voted this answer down because it does not concisely and precisely answer the question, which by the way, is very clear. Instead of answering the question first, the author starts with a lecture that drowns the reader. IMHO, it would have been better to 1) answer the question exactly, to the point, then 2) explain the risks.

Comment: @zinczinc Ok, thank you for your feedback. The problem I see with putting the answer first and the explanation later is that they will never read the important parts. The lecture I drown the reader with is actually far more important than the answer at the end, and IMHO the background I provide is pretty important to making those choices. But hey, if you want to submit a one-line answer because you think that is better for the OP, please feel free to use that portion of my answer to make a better one we can all learn from.

Comment: thanks for the hint regarding the double CHECKPOINT; I run it always only once and wondered, why my logfile (SIMPLE RECOVERY MODE) remains big...

Comment: Like mentioned in the comments section of a different answer: "yourdb_log" is the logical file name, which can be found in the database file properties section. I added single quotes around it and it worked.

Comment: If you have to run `ALTER DATABASE testdb SET RECOVERY FULL;`, then you need another FULL backup before you can take a log backup.

Comment: "If the log file will grow to the same size again, not very much is accomplished by shrinking it temporarily." Only on SO would someone suggest that bringing a broken mission-critical application back online is "not accomplishing much".  Wow.

Comment: @BryanWilliams So maybe you can shrink it temporarily, but if the problem is that the log file is FULL and can't grow anymore, shrinking isn't a fix anyway (and probably isn't even going to be possible). If you mean that you're shrinking one log file so that a _different_ database can have its files grow in that same place, ok, sure, but this is also a temporary fix that needs to be addressed at a higher level _also_. If your only solution for bringing your mission-critical application back online is to shrink a log file, this answer probably isn't for you.

Comment: @BryanWilliams Anyway, part of the sentiment here was aimed at users (and there have been many!) who aren't shrinking log files to bring a mission-critical application back online, they're just shrinking files because they're "too big." If they don't fix the reasons for them getting that big, they're just going to get that big again.

Answer (score 261):

```
-- DON'T FORGET TO BACKUP THE DB :D (Check [here][1]) 


USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (AdventureWorks2008R2_Log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

From: *[DBCC SHRINKFILE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)*

You may want to backup first.

Comment: This approach sets recover type to "FULL", even if recovery type was something else before

Comment: Worked like magic! Note that the name of the log file is actually its logical name (which can be found in db->properties->files)

Comment: I'd include a BACKUP DATABASE clause in this script, so nobody forgets this part. I say this, because some years ago I shrunk a database in a disk where it has too few free space. In the shrink process, the files were getting bigger, and an Out of Space error was thrown. Result: I lost the database. Luckly was a log database which had lose tolerance.

Comment: @Dragas There is a link to the official documentation in the answer, you may want to consider taking a look at it, at the official documentation. BTW a good DBA would not be looking in stackoverflow for how to clear a log, pretty sure they would know, but I am not a DBA :)

Comment: Didn't work at first until I realized that in SQL-Server 2016 the log file is actually lower-case "_log".  The 3rd command is case-sensitive.  Once I changed it to match exactly my database's log name, this worked!!

Comment: What bothered me is that this should have worked for me, but it didn't for my version of SQL Server. According to the documentation it should. While it did shrink my log, it did not truncate it, nor did it change my recovery to Simple. I had to do both in the GUI before it worked. SQL Server is not fun to admin compared to other alternatives.

Answer (score 196):

**DISCLAIMER:** Please read comments below this answer carefully before attempting it, and be sure to check the accepted answer. As I said nearly 5 years ago:

> if anyone has any comments to add for situations when this is NOT an
> adequate or optimal solution then please comment below

Turns out there were :-)

---

**Original Answer:**

- Right click on the database name.
- Select Tasks → Shrink → Database
- Then click <kbd>OK</kbd>!

I usually open the Windows Explorer directory containing the database files, so I can immediately see the effect.

*I was actually quite surprised this worked! Normally I've used DBCC before, but I just tried that and it didn't shrink anything, so I tried the GUI (2005) and it worked great - freeing up 17 GB in 10 seconds*

In Full recovery mode this might not work, so you have to either back up the log first, or change to Simple recovery, then shrink the file.  [thanks @onupdatecascade for this]

--

PS: I appreciate what some have commented regarding the dangers of this, but in my environment I didn't have any issues doing this myself especially since I always do a full backup first. So please take into consideration what your environment is, and how this affects your backup strategy and job security before continuing. All I was doing was pointing people to a feature provided by Microsoft!

Comment: glad to hear it worked for you too! if anyone has any comments to add for situations when this is NOT an adequate or optimal solution then please comment below.

Comment: In Full recovery mode this might not work, so you have to either back up the log first, or change to Simple recovery, then shrink the file.

Comment: @onupdatecascade - good call on full recovery trick. had another database with a huge log : switched to simple, then shrink database and switched back to full. log file down to 500kb!

Comment: simple shrink command from SQL GUI does not seems to work for me at all. I have tried it several times without any reduction in the size of transaction log. Am i missing something ??

Comment: did you turn off 'full recovery' mode and changed it to 'simple' mode? disclaimer: MAKE A BACKUP first if you do this. i've never had an issue but would hate for you to lose data

Comment: i dont need transaction lgo at all. i mean i am just working with some scratch data. I dont need any type of recovery. wahtever data i value , i just copy the table to new DB or some such thing. Can i work without trasanction log ? It grows too big and if i delete data out of large data it takes forever because it is recordng tx log. If i restrict , then it say sits full and increase it how to restric it or turn it off totally ??

Comment: Sorry. But this answer simply could NOT be MORE wrong. By shrinking the database you WILL grow the transaction log file. ANY time you move data around in a SQL Server database, you'll require logging - bloating the log file. 

To decrease log size, either set the DB to Simple Recovery OR (if you care/need logged data - and you almost always do in production) backup the log.

More Details in these simple, free, videos:
http://www.sqlservervideos.com/video/logging-essentials/
http://www.sqlservervideos.com/video/sql2528-log-files/

Comment: Wow, kudos for getting 1300+ rep for this answer, but it really is terrible advice.

Comment: In additional to what Michael and Aaron said, if you are switching back and forth between full and simple recovery model, you shouldn't be allowed to touch SQL Server until you've at least learned the basics.

Comment: Worst advice ever. This is actively dangerous advice and should be removed.

Comment: @RobertLDavis whoever said I switched back? ;-)

Comment: Here is an exaggeration to demonstrate what is happening and why shrinking is absolutely critical on a periodic basis: Record A is changed 1 million times before a backup is done. What is in the log? 999,999 pieces of data that are irrelevant. If the logs are never shrunk you will never know what the true operating expense of the database is. Also, you are hogging valuable resources on a SAN, most likely. Shrinking is good maintenance and keeps you in touch with your environment. Show me someone who thinks you should never shrink and I'll show you someone ignoring their environment.

Comment: this is perfectly acceptable for any dev/test DB which are 90% of the time the DB's were having to work with

Answer (score 59):

Below is a script to shrink the transaction log, but I’d definitely recommend backing up the transaction log before shrinking it.

If you just shrink the file you are going to lose a ton of data that may come as a life saver in case of disaster. The transaction log contains a lot of useful data that can be read using a third-party transaction log reader (it can be read manually but with extreme effort though).

The transaction log is also a must when it comes to point in time recovery, so don’t just throw it away, but make sure you back it up beforehand.

Here are several posts where people used data stored in the transaction log to accomplish recovery:

- *[How to view transaction logs in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509)*
- *[Read the log file (*.LDF) in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054)*

```
USE DATABASE_NAME;
GO

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
--First parameter is log file name and second is size in MB
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DATABASE_NAME_Log, 1);

ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

You may get an error that looks like this when the executing commands above

> “Cannot shrink log file (log file name) because the logical
>       log file located at the end of the file is in use“

This means that TLOG is in use. In this case try executing this several times in a row or find a way to reduce database activities.

Answer (score 39):

Here is a simple and **very inelegant** & **potentially dangerous**  way.

1. Backup DB
2. Detach DB
3. Rename Log file
4. Attach DB
5. New log file will be recreated
6. Delete Renamed Log file.

I'm guessing that you are not doing log backups. (Which truncate the log). My advice is to change recovery model from [full](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190217.aspx) to [simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164.aspx). This will prevent log bloat.

Comment: Respectfully, deleting/ renaming/ recreating/ replacing the log is a very bad idea. Shrink is must less risky, plus it's pretty simple to do.

Comment: +1 - Inelegant or not, this method has got me out of hot water a couple of times with database logs that have filled the entire disk, such that even a shrink command can't run.

Comment: Is there not a risk of uncheckpointed transactions existing in the log?

Comment: This might also be fine for smaller DB's, but if your have a 3 or 4 TB DB, it might not be the best solution.

Comment: This seems ok if you have been developing a system for a long time and loading/delete thousands of records during the dev period. Then when you want to use this database to deploy to live, the testing/development data that has been logged is redundant and therefore doesn't matter if its lost, no?

Comment: Yes development environments may not care about data integrity as is my case. But I'd like to know how you rename the log file? I can't find the place in SSMS to do that and Server12 doesn't give me access to the log directory.

Comment: Best solution for huge static or read only databases that have to be maintained periodically.

Answer (score 32):

If you do not use the transaction logs for restores (i.e. You only ever do full backups), you can set Recovery Mode to "Simple", and the transaction log will very shortly shrink and never fill up again.

If you are using SQL 7 or 2000, you can enable "truncate log on checkpoint" in the database options tab. This has the same effect.

This is not recomended in production environments obviously, since you will not be able to restore to a point in time.

Comment: Setting the recovery mode to simple will not, on its own, magically shrink the transaction log.

Comment: @Aaron Not on it's own, no. I assumed that the OP would be using their test database, and therefore "the transaction log will very shortly shrink", but you are correct in that it's more of a side effect: Recovery mode of simple will probably make you end up with a shrunken transaction log soon

Comment: "`Simple`...and never fill up again" -- not true.  I've seen it happen (in the past 48 hours) on a database where the Recovery Model was set to "SIMPLE".  The logfile's filegrowth was set to "restricted", and we'd been doing some immense activity on it... I understand that it was an unusual situation.  (In our situation, where we had plenty of disc space, we increased the logfile size, and set logfile filegrowth to "unrestricted"... which by the way --interface bug-- shows up, after the change, as "restricted" with a maxsize of 2,097,152 MB.)

Comment: @Doug_Ivison Yes, the transaction log will have open transactions in it, but they will be removed in simple mode once a checkpoint has taken place. This answer is only intended as a quick "my development/test box has a big transaction log, and I want it to go away so I don't need to worry about it too often", rather than ever intended to go into a production environment. To re-iterate: *Do not do this in production*.

Comment: That's all true, and I get that it was a development-only quick approach.  Why I commented:  until it happened to me, I actually thought the simple recovery model could NEVER fill up... and I think it took me longer to figure out / resolve, while I came to understand that unusually large transactions can do that.

Comment: Maybe after setting to full recovery mode, *then* [shrink (using the UI, according to this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log#comment1063171_459055) to see effects of decreased log size?

Answer (score 11):

The SQL Server transaction log needs to be properly maintained in order to prevent its unwanted growth. This means running transaction log backups often enough. By not doing that, you risk the transaction log to become full and start to grow.

Besides the answers for this question I recommend reading and understanding the transaction log common myths. These readings may help understanding the transaction log and deciding what techniques to use to "clear" it:

From *[10 most important SQL Server transaction log myths](http://www.sqlshack.com/10-important-sql-server-transaction-log-myths/)*:

> Myth: My SQL Server is too busy. I don’t want to make SQL Server transaction log backups
>
> One of the biggest performance intensive operations in SQL Server is an auto-grow event of the online transaction log file. By not making transaction log backups often enough, the online transaction log will become full and will have to grow. The default growth size is 10%. The busier the database is, the quicker the online transaction log will grow if transaction log backups are not created
> Creating a SQL Server transaction log backup doesn’t block the online transaction log, but an auto-growth event does. It can block all activity in the online transaction log

From *[Transaction log myths](http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/transaction-log-myths/)*:

> > Myth: Regular log shrinking is a good maintenance practice
>
> FALSE. Log growth is very expensive because the new chunk must be zeroed-out. All write activity stops on that database until zeroing is finished, and if your disk write is slow or autogrowth size is big, that pause can be huge and users will notice. That’s one reason why you want to avoid growth. If you shrink the log, it will grow again and you are just wasting disk operation on needless shrink-and-grow-again game

Answer (score 10):

This technique that John recommends is not recommended as there is no guarantee that the database will attach without the log file. Change the database from full to simple, force a checkpoint and wait a few minutes. The SQL Server will clear the log, which you can then shrink using DBCC SHRINKFILE.

Comment: ...but I have done it dozens of times without issue. perhaps you could explain why the db may not re-attach.

Comment: I have on occasion (not very often) seen the SQL Server not be able to attach the database back to the database when the log file has been deleted.  This leaves you with a useless MDF file.  There are several possibilities that can cause the problem.  Transactions pending rollback come to mind.

Comment: I agree with this tactic, but it should be reserved for cases where the log has blown up due to some unforeseen and/or extraordinary event. If you set up a job to do this every week, you're doing it very, very wrong.

Comment: Yes, this just happened to us.  We wanted to ditch 20G of log file as we'd just backed up the data before moving the database.  No way would MSSQL allow us to re-attach the new database without the humongous log file.

Answer (score 10):

Most answers here so far are assuming you do not actually need the Transaction Log file, however if your database is using the `FULL` recovery model, and you want to keep your backups in case you need to restore the database, then *do not* truncate or delete the log file the way many of these answers suggest.

Eliminating the log file (through truncating it, discarding it, erasing it, etc) will break your backup chain, and will prevent you from restoring to any point in time since your last full, differential, or transaction log backup, until the next full or differential backup is made.

From the [Microsoft article on`BACKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> We recommend that you never use NO_LOG or TRUNCATE_ONLY to manually
>   truncate the transaction log, because this breaks the log chain. Until
>   the next full or differential database backup, the database is not
>   protected from media failure. Use manual log truncation in only very
>   special circumstances, and create backups of the data immediately.

To avoid that, backup your log file **to disk** before shrinking it. The syntax would look something like this:

```
BACKUP LOG MyDatabaseName 
TO DISK='C:\DatabaseBackups\MyDatabaseName_backup_2013_01_31_095212_8797154.trn'

DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MyDatabaseName_Log', 200)
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, except for the `, 1)` part. The problem is that if you shrink it to 1 MB, the growth events leading to a *normal* log size will be quite costly, and there will be *many* of them if the growth rate is left to the default of 10%.

Answer (score 6):

First check the database recovery model. By default, SQL Server Express Edition creates a database for the simple recovery
model (if I am not mistaken).

Backup log DatabaseName With Truncate_Only:

```
DBCC ShrinkFile(yourLogical_LogFileName, 50)
```

SP_helpfile will give you the logical log file name.

Refer to:

*[Recover from a full transaction log in a SQL Server database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/873235/recover-from-a-full-transaction-log-in-a-sql-server-database)*

If your database is in Full Recovery Model and if you are not taking TL backup, then change it to SIMPLE.

Comment: This is the way that I clear log files on my dev boxes. Prod environments with all of the associated backup strategies etc I leave to the DBA's :-)

Comment: `TRUNCATE_ONLY` is no longer an option in current versions of SQL Server, and it's not recommended on versions that do support it (see [Rachel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14628788/61305)).

Answer (score 6):

Use the `DBCC ShrinkFile ({logicalLogName}, TRUNCATEONLY)` command. If this is a test database and you are trying to save/reclaim space, this will help.

Remember though that TX logs do have a sort of minimum/steady state size that they will grow up to. Depending upon your recovery model you may not be able to shrink the log - if in FULL and you aren't issuing TX log backups the log can't be shrunk - it will grow forever. If you don't need TX log backups, switch your recovery model to *Simple*.

And remember, never ever under any circumstances delete the log (LDF) file! You will pretty much have instant database corruption. Cooked!  Done! Lost data! If left "unrepaired" the main MDF file could become corrupt permanently.

Never ever delete the transaction log - you will lose data! Part of your data is in the TX Log (regardless of recovery model)... if you detach and "rename" the TX log file that effectively *deletes* part of your database.

For those that have deleted the TX Log you may want to run a few checkdb commands and fix the corruption before you lose more data.

Check out Paul Randal's blog posts on this very topic, *[bad advice](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/bad-advice/)*.

Also in general do not use shrinkfile on the MDF files as it can severely fragment your data. Check out his Bad Advice section for more info ("Why you should not shrink your data files")

Check out Paul's website - he covers these very questions. Last month he walked through many of these issues in his *Myth A Day* series.

Comment: +1 For being the first answer to mention that this may not be a good idea! The OP specifies a test database but it is a point well worth making for the more general case.

Comment: I should have added - If you delete the TX log - Update Resume!

Answer (score 5):

It happened with me where the database log file was of 28 GBs.

What can you do to reduce this? 
Actually, log files are those file data which the SQL server keeps when an transaction has taken place. For a transaction to process SQL server allocates pages for the same. But after the completion of the transaction, these are not released suddenly hoping that there may be a transaction coming like the same one. This holds up the space.

Step 1: 
First Run this command in the database query explored 
checkpoint

Step 2: 
Right click on the database 
Task> Back up
Select back up type as Transaction Log
Add a destination address  and file name to keep the backup data (.bak)

Repeat this step again and at this time give another file name

[image]

Step 3:
Now go to the database 
Right-click on the database

Tasks> Shrinks> Files 
Choose File type as Log
Shrink action as release unused space

[image]

Step 4:

Check your log file 
normally in SQL 2014 this can be found at

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014EXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

In my case, its reduced from 28 GB to 1 MB

Answer (score 4):

**To Truncate the log file:**

- Backup the database
- Detach the database, either by using Enterprise Manager or by executing : *Sp_DetachDB [DBName]*
- Delete the transaction log file. (or rename the file, just in case)
- Re-attach the database again using: *Sp_AttachDB [DBName]*
- When the database is attached, a new transaction log file is created.

**To Shrink the log file:**

- Backup log [DBName] with No_Log
- Shrink the database by either:

  Using Enterprise manager :-
  Right click on the database, All tasks, Shrink database, Files, Select log file, OK.

  Using T-SQL :-
  *Dbcc Shrinkfile ([Log_Logical_Name])*

You can find the logical name of the log file by running sp_helpdb or by looking in the properties of the database in Enterprise Manager.

Comment: Never ever delete the transaction log.  Part of your data is in the Log.  Delete it and database will become corrupt.  I don't have rep to down vote.

Comment: For me DBCC SHRINKFILE not reduce log file ldf (Recovery is SIMPLE). For me log_reuse_wait_desc not returns any data. DBCC SQLPerf(logspace) return 99,99% Log Space Used DBCC LOGINFO returns 11059 rows, all Status = 2.

Comment: @Kiquenet I suspect you need to change Recover Models or perform a *Log* backup first.  If the space is used -- well -- that is your data, waiting to be committed and backed up.  The easy way out is to switch to Simple recovery model which should reduce your log used space immediately.  Then you can shrink the log and return to Full recovery.   If this is just a Test or Dev env you can stay in Simple recovery and the log won't grow.

Answer (score 3):

To my experience on most SQL Servers there is no backup of the transaction log.
Full backups or differential backups are common practice, but transaction log backups are really seldom.
So the transaction log file grows forever (until the disk is full).
In this case the **recovery model** should be set to "**simple**".
Don't forget to modify the system databases "model" and "tempdb", too.

A backup of the database "tempdb" makes no sense, so the recovery model of this db should always be "simple".

Comment: Just setting the database to simple won't shrink the log file, in whatever state it's currently in. It just may help prevent it from growing further (but it still could).

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a backup of the MDB file.
2. Stop SQL services
3. Rename the log file
4. Start the service

(The system will create a new log file.)

Delete or move the renamed log file.

Answer (score 2):

Database → right click *Properties* → file → add another log file with a different name and set the path the same as the old log file with a different file name.

The database automatically picks up the newly created log file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
USE DatabaseName

GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE( TransactionLogName, 1)

BACKUP LOG DatabaseName WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

DBCC SHRINKFILE( TransactionLogName, 1)

GO
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE_ONLY` is no longer an option in current versions of SQL Server, and it's not recommended on versions that do support it (see [Rachel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14628788/61305)).

Comment: It works for me using MSSQL Server 2005 Standard edition

Answer (score 1):

Slightly updated answer, for MSSQL 2017, and using the SQL server management studio.
I went mostly from these instructions https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transaction-log-backup-truncate-and-shrink-operations/

I had a recent db backup, so I backed up the transaction log.  Then I backed it up again for good measure.
Finally I shrank the log file, and went from 20G to 7MB, much more in line with the size of my data.
I don't think the transaction logs had ever been backed up since this was installed 2 years ago..  so putting that task on the housekeeping calendar.

Comment: Great.  I recommend performing another backup after shrinking.  Otherwise, when you restore you'll be back at the 20Gb size.  If this is at all a production like system you might want to run the defrag scripts before doing this backup.  The reason for the "after" backups is you won't lose all your hard work reclaiming space etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup DB
2. Detach DB
3. Rename Log file
4. Attach DB (while attaching remove renamed .ldf (log file).Select it and remove by pressing Remove button)
5. New log file will be recreated
6. Delete Renamed Log file.

This will work but it is suggested to take backup of your database first.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers did not work for me: It was not possible to create the checkpoint while the db was online, because the transaction log was full (how ironic). However, after setting the database to emergency mode, I was able to shrink the log file:

```
alter database <database_name> set emergency;
use <database_name>;
checkpoint;
checkpoint;
alter database <database_name> set online;
dbcc shrinkfile(<database_name>_log, 200);
```

Answer (score -2):

DB Transaction Log **Shrink to min size**:

1. Backup: Transaction log
2. Shrink files: Transaction log
3. Backup: Transaction log
4. Shrink files: Transaction log

I made tests on several number of DBs: **this sequence works**.

It usually **shrinks to 2MB**.

OR by a script:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @DB_LogFileName nvarchar(255);
SET @DB_Name = '<Database Name>';               --Input Variable
SET @DB_LogFileName = '<LogFileEntryName>';         --Input Variable
EXEC 
(
'USE ['+@DB_Name+']; '+
'BACKUP LOG ['+@DB_Name+'] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY ' +
'DBCC SHRINKFILE( '''+@DB_LogFileName+''', 2) ' +
'BACKUP LOG ['+@DB_Name+'] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY ' +
'DBCC SHRINKFILE( '''+@DB_LogFileName+''', 2)'
)
GO
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE_ONLY` is no longer an option in current versions of SQL Server, and it's not recommended on versions that do support it (see [Rachel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14628788/61305)).