# This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, ado.net

Code:

I am trying to run this function but it throws error:
**This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.**

I have used every other way but not working. I have used it without `USING` but still same error.

Why?

```
public Boolean AddWorkProgress(int WorkID, int ContractorID, float PhysicalProgress, 
  decimal FinancialProgress, int UserID, int OrgID, float FinancialProgressPecentage)
{
   SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand("AddWorkProgress", DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection());
   SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   using (SqlTransaction sqlTrans = SqlCom.Connection.BeginTransaction()) 
   {
      SqlCom.Transaction = sqlTrans;

      try
      {
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_ID", WorkID);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contractor_ID", ContractorID);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhysicalProgress", PhysicalProgress);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinancialProgress", FinancialProgress);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrgID", OrgID);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_WebUsers_UserID", UserID);
         SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinancialProgressPercentage", FinancialProgressPecentage);
         SqlParameter SqlParamReturnStatus = new SqlParameter("@ReturnStatus", SqlDbType.Bit);
         SqlCom.Parameters.Add(SqlParamReturnStatus);
         SqlParamReturnStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         SqlParameter SqlParamReturnStatusMessage = new SqlParameter("@ReturnStatusMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
         SqlCom.Parameters.Add(SqlParamReturnStatusMessage);
         SqlParamReturnStatusMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
         DataBaseConnection.CloseConnection();

         string ReturnStatusMessage = Convert.ToString(SqlParamReturnStatusMessage);
         Boolean ReturnStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(SqlParamReturnStatus.Value);
         // ProgressID = Convert.ToInt64(SqlParamReturnProgressID.Value);

         sqlTrans.Commit();
         return ReturnStatus;
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         sqlTrans.Rollback();
         sqlTrans.Dispose();

         throw ex;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: looks to me like you close the connection before you commit the transaction

Comment: You should probably be putting your connection in a `using` block as well.

Comment: The catch block is redundant too. The `using` block will rollback *and* dispose the transaction.

Comment: Why you using transaction at all? You executes only one procedure

Comment: Also, the connection should be placed in a `using` statement too. Right now, any error will leave the connection open

Comment: BTW, closing the connection without commiting the transaction results in a rollback. Whatever that stored procedure did, disappeared when `CloseConnection()` was called

Answer (score 4):

You're closing connection before commiting transaction:

```
DataBaseConnection.CloseConnection();
// skipped code
sqlTrans.Commit();
```

As from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Both Commit and Rollback generates an InvalidOperationException if the
>   connection is terminated or if the transaction has already been rolled
>   back on the server.

This is exactly your case - connection gets closed before commit/rollback of transaction.

Comment: I doubt it will be comitted. Will make more sense if it will be rolled back in that case.

Comment: @Evk I agree, it was incorrect wording. I've modified the answer to remove possible mislead.

Comment: Will be even more clear if you write that closing connection rollbacks all pending transactions started with connection.BeginTransaction :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't rollback or commit a transaction if the connection is closed. When the connection closes, SQL Server rolls back any open transactions anyway.

The `catch` block is redundant too. A transaction gets rolled back when it gets disposed, unless `Commit()` was called.

Finally, the connection is handled in an unsafe manner. If any error occurs before `CloseConnection()` the connection will be left open.

Using the connection and transaction in the correct manner simplifies the code a lot:

```
var SqlCom = new SqlCommand("AddWorkProgress");
SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//... prepare the command. No need to use a connection

using(var connection=DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection())
using(var transaction= connection.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    SqlCom.Connection=connection;
    SqlCom.Transaction=transaction;

    SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();

    //Process the results
}
```

That's it. The connection will close when the `using` block finishes. The transaction will be rolled back if `Commit()` isn't called, which can only happen in case of an error.

Once you separate the construction of the stored procedure from its execution, you can simplify the code further. For example, you can create the command only once, when the class or application gets initialized. Each time you want to execute it, you just set the connection and parameter values, eg:

```
public Boolean AddWorkProgress(int WorkID, int ContractorID, float PhysicalProgress, decimal FinancialProgress, int UserID, int OrgID, float FinancialProgressPecentage)
{
    using(var connection=DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection())
    using(var transaction= connection.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        _addProgressCmd.Parameters["@Work_ID"].Value=WorkID;
        ....
        _addProgressCmd.Connection=connection;
        _addProgressCmd.Transaction=transaction;

        _addProgressCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();

        var status=(bool)_addProgressCmd.Parameters["@ReturnStatus"].Value;
        var statusMsg=(string)_addProgressCmd.Parameters["@ReturnStatusMessage"].Value;

        //Process the results
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers do not solve your problem then you might want to check that your database and table are set up correctly.

A missing primary key can in some cases give the same error as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62796183/9192995).