# ZombieCheck Exception - This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable -- during simple commit

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have the following code which performs a commit of a single row to a database table (SQL 2008 / .NET 4)

```
using (var db = new MyDbDataContext(_dbConnectionString))
{
    Action action = new Action();
    db.Actions.InsertOnSubmit(dbAction);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Normally everything is fine, but once in a while I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
```

There are a number of similar questions on SO but I after reading them I cannot work out the cause.

Could this be simply due to a SQL timeout (the exception occurs close to 25s after the call is made)? Or should I expect a SQL timeout exception in that case?

Does anyone know what else may cause this?

Comment: Even if you get the exception, is the entity saved in the DB?

Answer (score 14):

The [`DataContext.SubmitChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) method has the following code lines in it's body:

```
// ...
try
{
    if (this.provider.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        this.provider.ClearConnection();
    }
    if (this.provider.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        this.provider.Connection.Open();
        flag = true;
    }
    dbTransaction = this.provider.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    this.provider.Transaction = dbTransaction;
    new ChangeProcessor(this.services, this).SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    this.AcceptChanges();
    this.provider.ClearConnection();
    dbTransaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    if (dbTransaction != null)
    {
        dbTransaction.Rollback();
    }
    throw;
}
// ...
```

When the connection times out, the `catch` block is executed and the [`dbTransaction.Rollback();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction.rollback.aspx) line will throw a [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

If you had control over the code, you could catch the exception like this:

```
catch
{
    // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
    try
    {
        if (dbTransaction != null)
        {
            dbTransaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
        // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
        // a closed connection.
        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
    }
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

YES! I had the same issue.  The scary answer is that SQLServer sometimes rolls back a transaction on the server side when it encounters an error, and does not pass the error back to the client.   YIKES!

Look on the Google Group microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet for ["SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck error"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/pmrOeuRBoog) Colberd Zhou [MSFT] explains it very well.

and see aef123's comment on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611700/sqltransaction-has-completed)

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that connection closes earlier that transaction commits. Then the transaction is rolled back. [Check this article on MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/08/24/zombie-check-on-transaction-error-this-sqltransaction-has-completed-it-is-no-longer-usable.aspx).