# Shrinking db log file in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, logfile

I have 60 GB log file(.ldf) file.Can anyone please provide me exact steps to shrink this file?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Read this answer by Aaron Bertrand more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18292136/2203084

Comment: Not so simple (to understand the actual problem). 1) Confirm you need Recovery model: Full and not just SImple.  That will solve your future problems.  2) Make sure the backup and truncate log is working, as it may be a problem with your backups.

Comment: I'm sure that by searching for that on Google will also provide you with "Exact Steps" to shirk this file.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne:Recovery Model is Full.

Comment: If you are not doing transaction log backups (or don't need up-to-the-minute) data, i.e. daily backups will do, then you can make it simple, which will avoid future very large transaction logs.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne:i need up-to-the minute data then what should i do?

Comment: Then make sure that your backups are happening properly AND if you look at the files to see that there is ample space in the log file (
DBCC SHOWFILESTATS WITH NO_INFOMSGS
;DBCC sqlperf(logspace) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
).  Then after the backup (with truncate) is done, then run: DBCC SHRINKFILE (<FileName>, <TargetSize>) WITH NO_INFOMSGS