# SQL Server log file over 5GB in size

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I notice that my database size is over 5GB in size around 98% of this is taken by log file while `.mdf` file size is around 10MB.

- I tried shrinking database that reduced space by 2MB
- Then I tried shrinking data file both `.mbf` & `.ldf` which hardly reduced space by 10-15mb.

When I take full backup my `.bak` file size is around is 18MB why so and how can I reduce the log file so that I don't have to worry about disk space?

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18292136/2203084

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using this SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
 DBCC SHRINKFILE (yourdatabase_Log, 1)
```

i.e, you first make your recovery model to Simple(*which I guess is set to Full presently*)

However if you want to truncate the log file you can use this command

```
BACKUP LOG  yourdatabase WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE (yourdatabase_Log, 1)
```

Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker:- So you need to set it as Simple!