# SQL Transaction Logs getting bigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have 2 databases. I have created a logic where firstly i delete all the data from Database2 with Truncate & then copy all the data from Database1 to Database2 with INSERT INTO.

This process runs every 2 days. The size of Database1 is around 1 GB.

This was all working good but now suddenly i started running out of space. My C: drive just got full & the reason i found was Transaction Log of Database2. Every time i did the above mentioned process which runs with MVC Website application, the Transaction Log goes increasing & increasing.

I can afford to lose data from Database2 didn't want Transaction Logs. 
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Why not avoid transactions all together and just backup DB1 and attach it as DB2?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to shrink your log file.

```
USE YourDatabaseName;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (YourDatabaseName_Log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Further reading: [How do you clear the SQL Server transaction log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log)

Answer (score 0):

Turn your transaction logging on the database 2 to simple:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: what is the default model?

Comment: Default model is FULL

Comment: @samithagun, the default recovery model for new databases is that of the model system database. If you change the model database to `SIMPLE`, new databases for the instance will be `SIMPLE` going forward.