# How to handle melon of record in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, execution-time, filegroup

In SQL server every time i got **Filegroup** is full, **Execution timeout**. How can i release some space in **SQL database**.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)

Comment: Question is not clear. Please provide more details

Comment: Your error is a command timeout - which is generally caused by blocking. Why do you think this is related to a <filegroup full> issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the SQL Server Database Size.

Step 1: Right-click on the database name >> Tasks >> Shrink >> Database.
[image]
Step 2: Then Click OK.
[image]

for more details you can read the following blog https://stackoverflow.com/a/18292136/1805776