# Sql Server LDF file taking too large space

Tags: sql-server

Why is my database log file taking to high space? Its almost taking up `30GB` of my HDD. Even after deleting `1,000,000` records, its not freeing up any space.
So,
 
`1.`Why is the log file taking this much space (`30gb`)?
`2.`how can I free up the space?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 1.Why is the log file taking this much space (30gb)?

- Or because of your recovery not SIMPLE and ldf grown eventually to such size
- Or because there was a large one-time DML operation
- Or because of other reasons, as noted by @sepupic in another answer

> 2.how can I free up the space?

- IF recovery is other than SIMPLE:

  - Firstly backup transaction log file
  - Perform a shrink, like `DBCC SHRINKFILE(2,256)`
- IF recovery is SIMPLE:

  - Just shrink it to desired size, like `DBCC SHRINKFILE(2,256)`

If the database log still did not reduce to a target size, then the exact reason to be checked, by using a code snippet of @sepupic

---

Some members still give and advice to physicaly remove LDF files.

I highly suggest to not do this. Remarkable related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log/459055) of Aaron Bertrand:

> **Some things you don't want to do:**
>
> Detach the database, delete the log file, and re-attach. I can't
>   emphasize how dangerous this can be. Your database may not come back
>   up, it may come up as suspect, you may have to revert to a backup (if
>   you have one), etc. etc.

Comment: For me DBCC SHRINKFILE not reduce log file ldf (Recovery is SIMPLE). For me log_reuse_wait_desc not returns any data. DBCC SQLPerf(logspace) return 99,99% Log Space Used DBCC LOGINFO returns 11059 rows, all Status = 2.

How get large one-time DML operations ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, it worth to check what exactly prevents shrinking by: `select name, log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where name = 'yourDB'`

Comment: For me log_reuse_wait_desc **not returns any data**

Answer (score 15):

> 1. Why is the log file taking this much space (30gb)?

It was because the `Autogrowth / Maxsize` was set `200,000 MB`

> 2. how can I free up the space?

As described [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/) i used the following command and the file is now less than `200mb`

```sql
    
ALTER DATABASE myDatabaseName
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (myDatabaseName_log, 1)
GO
ALTER DATABASE myDatabaseName_log
SET RECOVERY FULL
```

I have also set `Autogrowh/Maxsize` in the database properties to `1000` as `Limited` (See the image below).

[image: Database Propertis => Files in SSMS]

The link describes more, so I recommend referring it for detailed description and other options.
Thanks @hadi for the link.

Comment: your database will be non-operational after the transaction log file reaches 1000 MB. And because you set it to **FULL** recovery, it will happen quite soon ;)

Comment: why? and why sql server provides that option if so?

Comment: because you enabled FULL recovery but perhaps do not understand when it should be used and what side effects it can bring. In very short: if you have full recovery enabled and do not perform transaction log backups, your log will keep growing and when it will the limit you set recently, your database will not be able to execute any DML operation, like INSERT/DELETE etc. I think this is a good article to explain in more details: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5343/understanding-sql-server-recovery-models-and-transaction-log-use/

Answer (score 5):

> Why is my database log file taking to high space?

There can be more causes, not only the 2 mentioned in another answer.

You can find the exact reason using this query:

```
select log_reuse_wait_desc
from sys.databases
where name = 'myDB';
```

Here is a link to the BOL article that describes all the possible causes under `log_reuse_wait`:
[sys.databases (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> how can I free up the space?

First you should determine the cause using the query above, then you should fix it, for example, if it's broken `replication` you should remove it or fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a maintenance job to [backup the transaction log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), and do it ***often***: like every 10 minutes or so.

A FULL backup once per day isn't good enough.

Alternatively, you can change the [Recovery Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) of the database from `FULL` to `SIMPLE`. But if you do this, you'll lose the ability to do point-in-time restores.

Comment: Just want to mention that log can grow to large size even in SIMPLE recovery by running some large DML operation. As an example - TEMPDB, it cannot have other recovery than simple but out of space of its log file can be a reason of a server downtime..

Answer (score 0):

In my case the DB names was with bad characters so the script doesn't worked.

I found out and follow this [article](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/LogFileSizeOnSqlServer), which worked perfect in two steps: changing backup log from full to simple and shrink DB log file more than 95%